# Enable a button when an HTML select option is selected and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something. I have this in a while loop:

```
<tr>
<th>Order status</th>
<td>
<form class='update-status'>
<select name='status_id'class='status'>
<option selected='selected'>Order received</option>
<option value='2'>Processing</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' title='Click to update the status of this order' disabled>Update order status</button>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

What I need is that the button gets enabled only if the option with value 2 is selected and vice-versa! I think I need to use something like `$('select').on('change', function()` but I don't know how to get the value of the option.
 I'm trying with:

```
$('.status').change(function()
{
    if ($('select option:selected').val() === 2)
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find( 'button' ).prop("enabled", true);
    }
});
```

But this is not working. I apreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific what do you have in the while loop and if possible share the JavaScript that you have as well

Comment: @ChavdarSlavov The only javascript that I think can help me is that I entered in question, my other attempts failed. The while loop displays all the orders present in the table in my database.

Comment: I'm not seeing the loop and you shouldn't use closest('tr') because the button and select are both in the same level and you can use .siblings() instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try utilizing [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

> **Description:** Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it
>   retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
$(".status").change(function() {
  var button = $(this).next("button");
  if (this.value == "2") {
    button.prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    button.prop("disabled", true)
  } 
});
```

```js
$(".status").change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var button = $(this).next("button");
  if (this.value == "2") {
    button.prop("disabled", false);       
  } else {
    button.prop("disabled", true)
  };
  console.log(button.prop("disabled"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Order status</th>
      <td>
        <form class='update-status'>
          <select name='status_id' class='status'>
            <option selected='selected'>Order received</option>
            <option value='2'>Processing</option>
          </select>
          <button title='Click to update the status of this order' disabled>Update order status</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you could turn that into a simple one-liner: `$(this).next("button").prop("disabled", this.value == "2")`

Comment: @redbmk For expected result described , should corresponding logic of to return `false` if `this.value == "2"`  be `$(this).next("button").prop("disabled", this.value != "2") ` ?

Comment: @guest271314, oops, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You can check value of `select` and use `.removeAttr()` to remove `disabled`.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "2") {
        $('#sub_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    } 
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obuhd1uj/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think they will remove it because you cited w3schools. About the problem, I had seen this solution, but does not work for me because I have several elements with the same name because of the while loop.

Comment: Why can't I cite w3schools? I'm obviously new here.

Comment: They don't like w3schools. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer :

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <form class='update-status'>
<select name='status_id' id="select">
<option selected='selected'>Order received</option>
<option value='2'>Processing</option>
<option value='3'>Something else</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' title='Click to update the status of this order' id="button" disabled>Update order status</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select').change(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();

            if(value == 2){

                $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');

            }else{
                $('#button').prop("disabled", true );
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this won't work for me because I have multiple with the same name/ID because the while loop! I think I need to use `closest`.

Comment: Id of what if your talking about the id used in html it should be UNIQUE

Comment: check my modification on my answer i think this is what you are looking for

Comment: This won't work for me because I have multiple elements because of the while loop. Please take a look in the question, I've updated it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your html(changed minor things):

```
<form class='update-status'>
<select id='status_id'>
<option value='1' selected='selected'>Order received</option>
<option value='2'>Processing</option>
</select>
<button type='submit' id='btn' title='Click to update the status of this order' disabled>Update order status</button>
</form>
```

Here is the working js of what you need:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
       if(this.value == 1)
           $('#btn').attr("disabled", true);
        else
           $('#btn').attr("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6mtwumce/6/

Comment: Be aware that this solution will not work with more select values. It is better to switch it around so you can check the value that enables the button.

Comment: Side note, from http://api.jquery.com/prop/ - "The `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method."